# Trouble scraping details from url in R

Tags: r, selenium

I am having trouble scraping details from the url below using selenium.
Once I connect to the URL with selenium, I'd like to scrape the following details and put them in a data frame:

1. first name
2. last name
3. title
4. email
5. address
6. phone #

However, I cannot get any meaningful results with the function I have created below. What am I doing wrong?

I still get an error ***"Error in firstname[n] <- str_extract(str_subset(i, pattern_first), pattern_first) :
replacement has length zero"***

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

This is my code so far:

```
library(RSelenium)
library(stringr)

web_url = 'https://business.okstate.edu/msis/directory.html'
rD = rsDriver(verbose=FALSE, browser = 'firefox', port = 4566L)

remDr = rD$client

remDr$open()

remDr$navigate(web_url)

# Get list of names
names = '//div[@class="panel panel-default"]/div'
person_elem = remDr$findElements(using = "xpath", value = names)
names_list = unlist(sapply(person_elem, function(x) {x$getElementText()}))
names_list

# Get credentials. This is where I plan getting all other details
credentials = '//iv[@class="col-xs-9"]/p'
credent_elem = remDr$findElements(using = "xpath", value = credentials)
credentials_list = unlist(sapply(person_elem, function(x) {x$getElementText()}))
credentials_list

# Check lengths
length(names_list) == length(credentials_list)

# Create vectors to hold the data scraped
# from the website
rip_person = function(name, credent) {
  #name = names
  #credent = credentials_list
  firstname = vector()
  lastname = vector()
  title = vector()
  email = vector()
  address = vector()
  phone = vector()
  
  pattern_first = '^[A-Za-z]+[:punct:]*[A-Za-z]*\\s'
  pattern_last = '\\s{1}[A-Za-z]+\\s{0,1}[A-Za-z]*'
  pattern_email = '[a-zA-Z0-9-_.]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-_.]+'
  pattern_title = '([A-Za-z0-9\\.-]+)([A-Za-z0-9\\.-]+)\.\s+([A-Za-z0-9\\.-]+)\s+([A-Za-z0-9\\.-]+)\s+([A-Za-z0-9\\.-]+)\s+([A-Za-z0-9\\.-]+)\s+([A-Za-z0-9\\.-]+)'
  pattern_phone = '(?:(([1-9]|[0-9][0-9]|[0-9][0-9][0-9])(?:[.-])?)?(([2-9]1[02-9]|[2-9][02-8]1|[2-9][02-8][02-9])|([0-9][1-9]|[0-9]1[02-9]|[2-9][02-8]1|[2-9][02-8][02-9]))(?:[.-])?)?([2-9]1[02-9]|[2-9][02-9]1|[2-9][02-9]{2})(?:[.-])?([0-9]{4})'
  
  n = 0
  
  for (i in name) {
    n = n + 1
    firstname[n] = str_extract(str_subset(i, pattern_first), pattern_first)
    lastname[n] = str_extract(str_subset(i, pattern_last), pattern_last)
  }
  
  f = 1
  
  for (t in credent) {
    emailtemp = str_extract(str_subset(t, pattern_email), pattern_email)
    
    if(length(emailtemp != 0))
      email[f] = emailtemp
    if(str_detect(t, '') != FALSE) {
      #cat('Data: "', t, '"\n', 'Email: ', emailtemp, '\n', 'Count: ', f, '\n')
      #cat(str_detect(t, ''), '\n')
      titletemp = str_replace(t, pattern_email, "")
      titletemp = str_replace_all(titletemp, '\n', " ")
      title[f] = titletemp
      f = f + 1
    }
  }
  
  new_dataframe = data.frame(firstname, 
                             lastname, 
                             email, 
                             title, 
                             stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  
  return(new_dataframe)
}



directory_df = rip_person(names_list, credentials_list)
```

Comment: This error has nothing to do with web scraping. One of your inputs must not have any matches, so `str_subset` returns nothing, `str_extract` gets and returns nothing, and you are trying to put nothing in `firstname[n]` - hence the error about "replacement has length zero".

Comment: I'm not really sure why you're using **both** `str_subset` and `str_extract` with the same pattern. You could probably simplify to `firstname[n] = str_extract(i, pattern_first)` and do okay, because `str_extract` will return `NA` if there are no matches (as long as there is input). But also `str_extract` is vectorized, so I'm not sure that you need a loop at all, `firstname = str_extract(name, pattern_first)` might work all at once.